# Broke my scikit-learn installation by running `pip3 install sklearn` on accident

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, conda

I was trying to update scikit-learn and accidentally ran `pip3 install sklearn` instead of `pip3 install scikit-learn`. This installed ... something.

```
In [1]: import sklearn as skl                                                   

In [2]: skl.__version__                                                         
Out[2]: '0.23.1'

In [3]: dir(skl)                                                                
Out[3]: 
['__SKLEARN_SETUP__',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__check_build',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_config',
 '_distributor_init',
 'base',
 'clone',
 'config_context',
 'exceptions',
 'get_config',
 'logger',
 'logging',
 'os',
 'set_config',
 'setup_module',
 'show_versions',
 'sys',
 'utils']
```

but this module is missing all of the core attributes of scikit-learn, including `model_selection`, `tree`, etc.

I tried running `pip3 uninstall sklearn` and then `pip3 install scikit-learn`, but the problem persists. I also tried the equivalent Conda commands, since I am using the Conda distribution.

Short of reinstalling Python from scratch, is there a way to get my installation of scikit-learn working again?

Comment: does importing `model_selection` or `tree` give any errors?

Comment: Oh, this fixes it! Why doesn't importing all of scikit-learn work at once? Are other packages like that, too...?

Comment: Yes. This is pretty normal, it's the default way packages work

Comment: The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information. From here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 0):

sklearn is meant to install scikit-learn package, even if you install as pip install scikit-learn you'll have to use it as sklearn in the code. What you can do it try uninstalling sklearn, scikit-learn and reinstall it. Or maybe there could be a conflict because you are using both conda and pip. Lemme know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete. here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Also see the [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) module. You can also use `help()` in the interactive interpreter which would generate the documentation you need.

Everything seems to be fine with your installation.